# Is Object.entries vulnerable to object injection attacks?

Tags: javascript, security, ecmascript-6

Let's say I want to build a table out of the key/values in a hash (not what I was doing, but similar enough). This is some code that would be delivered as part of a web page. The first version I wrote was like so:

```
let table = ''; 
Object.keys(foo).forEach(k => 
   // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-object-injection
   table += `||${k}|${foo[k]}||\n`
);
```

This triggered eslint's object injection error (which gives a lot of false positives but this object isn't coming from client input so it seems safe). But I wanted to try and refactor to get rid of the object injection issue:

```
let table = ''; 
Object.entries(foo).forEach(kv =>  table += `||${kv[0]}|${kv[1]}||\n`  );
```

That got rid of the `security/detect-object-injection` problem according to eslint. But I wanted to make sure and I can't find any discussion of how to work around this on here.

Is Object.entries better for iterating a hash (and values) vs. Object.keys when it comes to object injection?

Comment: You're only subject to object injection when `k` comes from an untrusted source and there are properties that shouldn't normally be exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two methods are equivalent. The difference is that in the second case, simple static analysis can determine that there's no object injection, since there's no use of a variable in the object index. In the first case, eslint can't tell that `k` is a safe index, but we can tell it easily because `Object.keys()` doesn't return user input.

The warning in the first version is a false positive. Object injection only occurs when the key comes from an untrusted source, since it allows them to access any property of the object. But if you're generating the list of properties in your code, it's not injection. The false positives happen because eslint doesn't know where `k` comes from in `foo[k]`, so it assumes the worst.

Read [The Dangers of Square Bracket Notation](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security/blob/master/docs/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation.md)

If your intent is to process all the properties, then there's no object injection when you get `k` from `Object.keys()`. And for the same reason, there's no object injection when you use `Object.entries()`, since it's getting the same keys and values.

Comment: Right, I read that a few minutes before posting this. But it seems like an odd oversight for eslint to error on one but not the other.

Comment: It warns about object injection whenever it sees an object being accessed using square brackets with a variable index. There are no variable indexes in the second version.

Comment: Then it seems like one has a possible but unlikely vulnerability while the other has no vulnerability

Comment: Neither of them has a vulnerability, since they're just two ways of doing the same thing. Square brackets are only an injection vulnerability if the index comes from the user.

Comment: That's generally true of all types of "injection" vulnerabilities. They're only a problem when you use user input in unsafe ways.

Comment: That's why this is a false positive: eslint can't determine that `k` is safe.

Comment: But the second one doesn't use square bracket (with a string value that could come from a malicious actor) notation at all -- since those values are only allowed to be numbers it seems safer

Comment: The first one uses square brackets, but not with user input, so there's no possible injection.

Comment: In one case it can be determined through static analysis that there's no injection possibility, in the other case it requires data flow analysis. That's hard for the computer, but easy for the programmer.